# When can helices form coiled-coils?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, protein-structure

The other day, my teacher suggested we find out whether a chain of the following amino acid sequence would be able to form a coiled-coil:

```
N-KIAEVRAQYEDVANKVRLIVE-C
```

Now, I can see that the chain is not amphiphilic as it does not alternate between polar and non polar amino acids. But when I come across an exercise of this type, how do I determine if it can actually form coiled coils? I can feel this will be a question on the final test. 
All help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cbic.200300781/full

Comment: Thank you so much!! I still have the same question. In every article I read, it says: A and G positions are *typically* hydrophobic. Why typically? Can positions that are not A and G be hydrophobic and still make up a coiled coil?

Comment: I don't know, but I expect that exceptions to the rule can be tolerated. You should ask your instructor what they are expecting from you.

Comment: Okay, thank you anyway for trying to help me. I, too, think that exceptions can be tolerated just by looking at alpha-keratin sequences that have so many exceptions and yet they form coiled coils! But it is hard to translate to simple cases as the one I proposed above. Thanks again!